# Liferay on JBoss 7

Tags: java, jboss, webserver, liferay

Liferay 6.0.6, by default doesnt bundle with JBoss 7. Did anyone successfully get liferay to work with JBoss 7. I'm a noob and would prefer if any of you can provide the instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I talked with some of the Liferay staff and they said JBoss AS 7 is still not supported or  usable with Liferay. I tried to use it and it failed completely. However, the Liferay staff is working on it AFAIK. So my answer is: wait, because the Liferay team will solve this problem.

Comment: FYI, its working well now.  I've been running liferay on JBoss7 for past few days.  You have to compile trunk manually and configure to use JBoss7 as app.server.

Comment: Any tips or guides for the configuration steps Greg? It would be useful to push this info back into the community if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Liferay 6.0.6 Is not compatible by default with JBoss 7 I was trying to doing it, but it's incompatible due ClassLoading issues to locate files by the portal.